# Designing a joint function

Tags: python

I have three functions, that each one of them calls internally the one below it:

- GetBitrateOverHTTP
- GetFilesizeOverHTTP
- Is_ServerSupportHTTPRange

Each function uses an HTTP Request on it's own. Which means the last function uses only a single HTTP Request, while the first uses three.

The `GetBitrateOverHTTP` function returns only the bitrate.

These functions work fine on their own, but now I want to get all the three outputs for a specific url.

I thought about:

1. Calling all the functions. The problem is that I'll make 6 HTTP Requests instead of 3.
2. Changing the definition of the functions to return others vars as well - but then it doesn't serve the basic purpose of the function - to return what it's meant to return.
3. Definite another function that doesn't use these definitions, but it doesn't seem smart to define again something that has been already coded.

Any help?

Comment: Well, as a quick fix you could set up proper caching directives... Maybe a better design would be GetFileInformation() that returns all three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a caching option. I created a dummy file and imported it.
Then I used in the beginning of each function:

```
if hasattr(dummy, 'GetFileSize_cache'):
    if dummy.GetFileSize_cache.has_key(url):
        return dummy.GetFileSize_cache[url]
    else:
        dummy.GetFileSize_cache = {}
```

and just before the return:

```
dummy.GetFileSize_cache[url] = file_size
```

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
class RemoteFile(...):

     ...

     def getInfo(self):
         resp = self._do_that_http_request(self.remotepath)
         return RemoteFileInfo(resp)


class RemoteFileInfo(...):

     def __init__(self, resp):
          self.bitrate = self._getbitrate(resp)
          self.filesize = self._getfilesize(resp)


     ...
```

and so on